# How to do multi-select in dnd-kit/core React JS

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, draggable, drag, dnd-kit

Please how can I implement multi-select in dnd-kit?

This storybook shows it in action but the full code wasn't shown [LINK TO STORYBOOK](https://5fc05e08a4a65d0021ae0bf2-yivpqsvbcy.chromatic.com/?path=/docs/presets-sortable-multiple-containers--multi-select)